# Android commons net ftp FTPClient send small file issue

Tags: android, upload, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have an issue with Apache commons-net-ftp library. What I do is send a small size MP3 files. The sizes are between 1 and 10 kb. All stages of algorithm pass well but there are NO files on FTP.

This is overview of the algorithm:

```
ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(mServerName));
ftpClient.login(mLogin, mPassword);
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(mWorkingDir);
if (ftpClient.getReplyString().contains("250")) {
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fullPathToLocalFile));
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ProgressInputStream progressInput = new ProgressInputStream(buffIn, callBack);
        boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile(serverFileName, progressInput);
        buffIn.close();
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
}
```

And this is out put:

```
FTP Uploader
- server: ftp.***.**.**
- login: freer_********
- password: ********
FTP Uploader upload file 1367302998934.mp3 full path /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/*********.*****.********/files/mp3/1367302998934.mp3
FTP replay: 250 OK. Current directory is /htdocs/mp3
ProgressInputStream update 1024
ProgressInputStream update 2048
ProgressInputStream update 3072
ProgressInputStream update 4070
ProgressInputStream update 4070
FTP result: true
```

As You see, all outputs are point to normal behavior but the is NO file on FTP server.
Does anyone has experience with same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for the post, the answer was very clear ...
The host provider I used has a service to monitor "mp3" content. It not allow to use mp3 files  to store on the host.

P.S. I wish to close this post but I don't know how.